# Python: Convert timestamp to number or string

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp

```
def GetLastSignificantTS(self,conn):
    conn=pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    db=conn.local
    return db.oplog.rs.find_one(sort=[('$natural', pymongo.DESCENDING)])['ts']
```

Result of the print of the returned value: Timestamp(1532221388, 1)

Problem: I need to create a directory named "1532221388" and not "Timestamp(1532221388, 1)"

Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on pymongo source code https://github.com/mher/pymongo/blob/master/bson/timestamp.py#L66 you can get actual time from time property `time`, so

```
db.oplog.rs.find_one(sort=[('$natural', pymongo.DESCENDING)])['ts'].time
```

should work.